# Assigning input values in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a hash and would like to take each of those values and put them inside a text field. The one problem with what I have written out now is that the values are hardcoded in the HTML so if changes are to be made in a text field by the user they would be ignored when submitting a form. Is there any way I can insert the data from my hashes without them being explicitly written as a `value` attribute but still be processed on submit?

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <table></table><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var data = [{name: "Object One", num: 1}, {name: "Object Two", num: 2}, {name: "Object Three",num: 3}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var dataNum   = "<td><input type='text' value='" + data[i]["num"] + "'></td>",
      dataName  = "<td><input type='text' value='" + data[i]["name"] + "'></td>";
  var $tr = "<tr>" + dataNum + dataName + "</tr>";

  $("table").append($tr);
}
```

Comment: I don't get "without them being explicitly written as a value attribute" part, but to be submitted as part of the form data the inputs must have `name` attribute specified.

Comment: correct. also values of dynamical generated elements can be updated with the .on

Comment: So if you were to inspect one of the input elements you'd see that it would look something like this `<input type="text" value="1">`.  I'm trying to make it so that there is no `value` attribute written in the DOM.

Comment: @CarlEdwards - that has not made it clearer. If you don't want `value` attribute - don't write it.

Comment: I'm trying to aim for the functionality that the `val()` method uses, where it would change the value of the text input but not write that particular value inside the DOM.

Comment: The value attribute is just used as the initial default. If the user edits the field, the changed value is what will be submitted.

Comment: @CarlEdwards - you are wrong thinking that `jQuery.val()` does something other than assigning element value property for html inputs.

Comment: So on submit of let's say a form using Ruby on Rails as a backend it would ignore the initial value if it differs from what's currently in the input? I never knew that was part of the DOM API.

Comment: ignore? The initial value is forgotten the moment it is changed - by user or javascript.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the backend is, Ruby or otherwise. The browser submits only the *current* value of each form element at the moment the submit occurs. (If changes made by the user were ignored then that would defeat the whole purpose of having user-enterable forms, wouldn't it?)

Comment: Are you trying to add values to the typed values of the user?

Comment: @ShlomiHassid It would work in a way where the information (the hash) was retrieved from an JSON call and if the user wanted to make changes they could go ahead and do so.

Comment: First thing I can point out is missing `name` with fields. Without name field value can not be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works as intended (at least what I understand you intended).  I had to add name attributes to each input which I used the iterator to create distinct ones.  I'm not sure what language you are using to process the form, but I know some will receive a list of attributes with the same name (`&name=Jeff&name=Jon&name=`...).

```
var dataNum   = "<td><input type='text' name='num" + [i] + "' value='" + data[i]["num"] + "'></td>"
```

I also attached an click handler to the submit button just to show that it works. The value attribute is necessary for populating the initial values of the form.  If the values are changed after the form is rendered, the changed value is what is submitted with the form.

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LhLkv2o8/) to test it out.

I'm not sure why you are trying to avoid `value=""` in the DOM.  You could do it, but you would have to set the value after the form was rendered by possibly creating another loop that walk through each row, walk through each cell of that row, and display set the value.

The structure of your map would certainly have to change. It would add extra code and would be completely unnecessary.